# Django 2.1 form (secondary form) want to able to make selection from primary field table using the foreign key

Tags: django-forms

I have 2 models e.g Product and inventory.

**Product**

Product 
Description 
Price
Quantity

**Inventory**

Product = Foreign Key Product - (productid)
Quantitysold
Price

so I want to make the inventory form, BUT I should display the Product to select in the inventory form. how to get that info in my inventory form to choose the product being updated and update the quantity in the Product table at the same time once submitted.

Comment: follow the link to understand django forms https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/ and please add what have you tried to avaid negative votes. dont forget to follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Basically managed to answer my own question. fact that you have classbased views. you only set up the field based views e.g.

class ContactAddInfo(CreateView):
     fields = ('company','title','firstname','lastname','phone','cell','email')
    model = Persons
    template_name = 'inservice/contactadd.html'

in the html . . 

  <table class="table table-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <td>CompanyName</td>
                            <td>{{form.company}}</td>
      </tr>